Using umlaut's in CSS font-family name?
Can I import and use font names with umlauts without simply ignoring/removing the umlaut from the name?
I'm importing like this:
// in HTML

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fonts.css" charset="UTF-8"/>

// in fonts.css

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Söhne';
    src: url('https://.../soehne-buch.woff2') format('woff2');
}

When I look at what the browser loaded I get this:
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SÃ¶hne';
    src: url('https://.../soehne-buch.woff2');
}

I've tried using character encoding instead but it doesn't get translated back to the umlaut in the browser (font-family: 'S\u00F6hne';).

Add  @charset "utf-8"; at the very beginning of your CSS file (nothing else should be written before it). See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@charset

Quite likely some files have mismatching encodings. Check your HTML and CSS files if they are actually saved in UTF8. In VS Code you see an indicator/field at the bottom right

Adding @charset "UTF-8"; doesn't fix.
Browser read as: font-family: 'SÃ¶hne';
Html is UTF-8 with BOM, CSS is UTF-8 and changing to UTF-8 with BOM doesn't fix.

However, putting the content of fonts.css in a  <style> in the HTML does work.

Are you sure it's utf-8? For example, latin-1 has umlauts too. If you would not tell the browser what it is, it could assume correctly by its own, maybe?

Thanks Kosh but, it is utf-8 as far as I can tell. VS-Code flags it as UTF-8 and still doesn't work even after I "Save With Encoding". Using style tags isn't really what I wanted but it'll work for now.

Well, it's more server-side qestion than CSs. What webserver are you using? What content-type / content-encoding headers do you see in network tab of devtools in the browser?

It's not necessary to use the original font name there. you might say e. g. font-family: "My Font" in @font-face and then use that name in your elements font-family declarations.
In fact, in this example I'm using "Imperial Script" font from Google fonts API.


@font-face {
  font-family: "My Font";
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/imperialscript/v6/5DCPAKrpzy_H98IV2ISnZBbGrVNfOuPk.woff2) format('woff2');
}

body {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "My Font";
}
It's not necessary to use the original font name there. you might say `font-family: "My Font"` in `@font-face` and then use that name in your elements `font-family` declarations. In fact, in this example I'm using "Imperial Script" font.




Due to some other constraints, it's desired to not change the name. I need to reference the font with the umlaut name.

@azulBonnet, then you have to deal with your server-side encoding.
